# AChartEngine - How to Add onClickListener and conflict between setClickEnabled() and setPanEnabled()

Tags: android, achartengine

I have an application that creates a bar chart based on Database values. In my main activity, I have this function:

```
public void onClick(View view){

    BarGraph bar = new BarGraph();
    bar.setCustomerCD(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()));

    yagoDB.open();
    ArrayList<String> stringList = yagoDB.getCustomerItem(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()));
    String[] itemArray = new String[stringList.size()];
    String[] returnedArray  = stringList.toArray(itemArray);

    bar.setItemCD(returnedArray);

    bar.setMax(yagoDB.getQtyMax(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())));

    bar.setItemCount(yagoDB.getItemCDCount(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())));

    ArrayList<Integer> stringList2 = yagoDB.getCustomerQtyInt(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()));
    yagoDB.close();
    int[] returnedQty  = convertIntegers(stringList2);

    bar.setQty(returnedQty);

    Intent barIntent = bar.getIntent(this);
    startActivity(barIntent);

}
```

In this function, I'm basically creating an instance of my BarGraph class, initializing some of its variables, after which, I call its getIntent function. Here is the getIntent() function in the BarGraph class, the rest of the class contains setters and getters:

```
public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

    int y[] = Qty;

    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Bar1");
    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        series.add("Bar" + (i + 1), y[i]);
    }

    // collection of series under one object, there could any number of series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); 
    dataSet.addSeries(series.toXYSeries()); 

    // customization of the chart

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); 
    renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 50d);
    renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(30);
    renderer.setLineWidth((float) 10.5d);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); 

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Sales for " + customerCD);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("\n \n Item Codes");
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setYTitle("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n Number of Orders");
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setShowGridX(true); // this will show the grid in graph
    mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5); 

    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(itemCount + 1);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);

    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max+1);
    //right, top, left, bottom
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{30,50,100,10});
    mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(20);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < ItemCD.length; i++){
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, ItemCD[i]);
    }

    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
    //mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);


    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false); // will fix the chart position

    //xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax
    mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{0, itemCount + 1, 0, max + 1});
    mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataSet,
            mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

    return intent;
}
```

I have googled examples and tutorials in how to and onClickListeners to a Graph generated by AChartEngine, but most of them involve generating the graph in the same class/activity. However, I noticed that the example that does not have to call an intent and I'm quite puzzled on how that worked.

Also, I had an issue where I set `setClickEnabled()` to true and it disabled `setPanEnabled()` from functioning properly.

So, several questions:

1. How do you add an onClickListener() on individual bars in a graph generated by AChartEngine?
2. Is there a way to enable `setClickEnabled()` and have it not conflict `setPanEnabled()`?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, see [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) example, starting at line #157.

For the second question, you can have them both enabled, but when you pan, the `setOnClickListener` will be running as well.

Comment: So I have to combine my BarGraph and MainActivity? I tried to incorporate the code after line 157, it did not work. I tried to adapt the code onto the `onResume()` of my MainActivity and it did not work as well. Will copy the example code and try to manipulate it.

Comment: Try to create a View rather than an Activity.